How can i strike out a double arrow but not the label?
I need to strike out a double arrow like in the picture.

Up to now i can strike only an arrow at a time with
\draw [<-, thick] ([xshift=-30]wd_top_junc.north east) to node[right]{$\begin{bmatrix}b_{1}\\b_{2}\end{bmatrix}$}([xshift=-30]nn_two_port.south east);
\draw [<-, thick] ([xshift=-36]wd_top_junc.north east) to node[strike out, draw, -]{}([xshift=-36]nn_two_port.south east);



Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add a minimal but complete (compilable) example of what you tried so far.

Welcome. // Besides noding around you can also draw 1 line, anchored to or relative to a useful position ...

Update:
It seems that it would be worthwhile to have a style that doubled whatever type of line style you wanted. It's an easy adaptation from the original solution below. For now, this only works on straight segments.
The style is called two and can be used with or without additional options.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing, calc}

\tikzset{
    two/.style={
        decoration={
            show path construction,
            lineto code={
                \path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst); \pgfgetlastxy{\a}{\b}
                \path (\tikzinputsegmentlast); \pgfgetlastxy{\x}{\y}
                \coordinate (uu) at ($(0,0)!.7mm!(\b-\y,\x-\a)$);
                \draw[#1]($(\a,\b)+(uu)$) to ($(\x,\y)+(uu)$);
                \draw[#1]($(\a,\b)-(uu)$) to ($(\x,\y)-(uu)$);
            }
        }, decorate
    },
    darrow/.default={}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[two] (0,0)--(2,1);
\draw[two={thick, orange, dashed, latex->}] (1,0)--(3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

The original solution can be obtained with the following code:
\draw[two={thick, ->}] (0,1) to node[right=1mm]{$\begin{bmatrix}b_{1}\\b_{2}\end{bmatrix}$} node[sloped]{/} (0,0);

Original answer:
You could define a new style darrow using pathreplacing to draw two arrows instead of the given line. Then node[sloped]{/} can be used for the strike, and an additional node or edge label can be used for the label.
For example,
\draw[darrow](0,0) to[edge label=x, edge label'=y]node[sloped]{/}(2,1);


In your example, a second node can be placed using right=.

Here is the code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing, calc}

\tikzset{
    darrow/.style={
        decoration={
            show path construction,
            lineto code={
                \path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst); \pgfgetlastxy{\a}{\b}
                \path (\tikzinputsegmentlast); \pgfgetlastxy{\x}{\y}
                \coordinate (uu) at ($(0,0)!.7mm!(\b-\y,\x-\a)$);
                \draw[->, #1]($(\a,\b)+(uu)$) to ($(\x,\y)+(uu)$);
                \draw[->, #1]($(\a,\b)-(uu)$) to ($(\x,\y)-(uu)$);
            }
        }, decorate
    },
    darrow/.default={}
}

\begin{document}

\vspace{2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[darrow=thick] (0,1) to node[right=1mm]{$\begin{bmatrix}b_{1}\\b_{2}\end{bmatrix}$} node[sloped]{/} (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

For a more slanted strike you could replace / with $\diagup$ (requires the amssymb package).

\draw[darrow=thick] (0,1) to node[right=1mm]{$\begin{bmatrix}b_{1}\\b_{2}\end{bmatrix}$} node[sloped]{$\diagup$} (0,0);

